# MAMP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: mamp, virtualhost

I got a little problem.

I made two virtual hosts "web-backend.local" and "oplossingen.web-backend.local".

But I always have a "500 Internal Server Error"

What am I doing wrong?

Hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

# MAMP VirtualHost Mappings
127.0.0.1 web-backend.local
127.0.0.1 oplossingen.web-backend.local
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
#NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

<VirtualHost web-backend.local:* >
DocumentRoot "/Users/yawuarsernadelgado/Documents/web-backend/cursus"
ServerName web-backend.local
<Directory "/Users/yawuarsernadelgado/Documents/web-backend/cursus">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes
    IndexOptions NameWidth=*
</Directory>
ServerAlias web-backend.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost oplossingen.web-backend.local:* >
DocumentRoot "/Users/yawuarsernadelgado/Documents/web-backend/oplossingen"
ServerName oplossingen.web-backend.local
<Directory "/Users/yawuarsernadelgado/Documents/web-backend/oplossingen">
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes
    IndexOptions NameWidth=*
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try looking in your apache log and your php log.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's reported `MAMP 500 Server Error`, it usually has little to do with MAMP.

500 internal server errors indicate you have crashed php pages. the solution is to add following error-reporting php code in your potential crashed page:

```php
    // display php error
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

if you use jQuery.Ajax, then I am afraid the code above in `action.php` won't work, there is another method, which is followed by

- add this to `index.html` or `index.php`

```html
<div id="show-error" style="position: fixed; z-index: 10000; height: 20vh; width: 100vw; background:#f08080; border-radius:20px; opacity: 0.8; display: flex; font-size: 2rem; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: none;"></div>
```

- in the php file called by ajax, set a success code and failue code

```js
try{
    // main   
    echo json_encode(['status' => 1, 'msg' => 'succeed']);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

- finallly, in the ajax javascript file, catch error if it occurs

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '../php/action.php', 
    method: 'POST',
    data: array('some data'), 
}).done(function(result){
    var output = JSON.parse(result);
    if(output.status == 0){
        $('#show-error').show();
        $('#show-error').html(output.msg);
        exit();
    }else{
        // no error occurred
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove  the following lines from httpd-vhosts.conf file from each virtual host:

```
<Directory "/Users/yawuarsernadelgado/Documents/web-backend/cursus">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes
    IndexOptions NameWidth=*
</Directory>
```

Worked for me :D